# Update Ansible Galaxy Page

Tags: ansible, ansible-role, ansible-galaxy

I've committed a role to galaxy.ansible.com

Now I've pushed some changes to the README files on Github.

How do I tell galaxy.ansible.com to re-read the Github repositories?

Answer (score 1):

From https://github.com/Dynatrace-Adam-Gardner/easytravel-distributed/tags I don't see any tags.

You need to `git push` your tag as well, see https://galaxy.ansible.com/docs/developers/workflow.html#release-process

You can see what Galaxy has imported from https://galaxy.ansible.com/my-imports?namespace=dynatrace_adam_gardner&selected=304470&page_size=10

Answer (score 0):

To take effect of changed Github repo you need to tag your Github repo with new ***version/tag*** and if the repo is linked correctly to your galaxy repo, once the tagging is done changes shall be reflected in your galaxy repo as well.

You can follow the release process for ansible-galaxy at following link: https://galaxy.ansible.com/docs/developers/workflow.html#release-process

Comment: https://github.com/Dynatrace-Adam-Gardner/easytravel-distributed. I committed "Release <1.1>" but it hasn't updated in galaxy.

Answer (score 0):

Guided by @justjais, the answer is:

1. `git tag -a v1.0 abc123` where `abc123` is the commit ID.
2. `git push --tags https://github.com/YOURUSER/YOURREPO`
3. Log into `galaxy.ansible.com` and click the `update` button.

Edit: Gundalow beat me to it. Re-assigning answer (credit where it's due).